# Why does Apache poi's Workbook.close() method write content to input file?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Apache poi's documentation (version 3.17) says

> void close()
>
> throws java.io.IOException
>
> Close the underlying input resource (File or Stream), from which the Workbook was read.

My code creates a workbook from a template file, does something with it and writes it to a new file. The template file should be left unchanged. But when I call the close() method, the file is changed in the same way as the output file.

Can someone explain this? Is there something like a built-in write() call in the close() method? Is this a bug or a feature?

My solution so far is to just leave away the close() call, but it feels incomplete somehow.

```
    String inPath = "/home/elmicha/test/template.xlsx";
    String outPath = "/home/elmicha/test/out.xlsx";

    try {
        Workbook xlsxFile = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(inPath));

        xlsxFile.getSheetAt(0).createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("test");

        try (FileOutputStream pOuts = new FileOutputStream(outPath)) {
            xlsxFile.write(pOuts);
            
        xlsxFile.close();
        
        }

    } catch (IOException | InvalidFormatException | EncryptedDocumentException ex) {
        //...
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's quite unusual. I don't see why the template file would be written to. It certainly wasn't my experience. You can try:

- Using `FileInputStream` instead of `File` to make it impossible to write to the template file.
- Using try-with-resources to automatically close `Workbook`.

Here's an example:

```
String inPath = "/home/elmicha/test/template.xlsx";
String outPath = "/home/elmicha/test/out.xlsx";

try (Workbook xlsxFile = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(inPath))) {
    xlsxFile.getSheetAt(0).createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("test");

    try (FileOutputStream pOuts = new FileOutputStream(outPath)) {
        xlsxFile.write(pOuts);
    }

} catch (IOException | InvalidFormatException | EncryptedDocumentException ex) {
    //...
}
```

Or perhaps:

```
String inPath = "/home/elmicha/test/template.xlsx";
String outPath = "/home/elmicha/test/out.xlsx";

try (Workbook xlsxFile = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(inPath));
    FileOutputStream pOuts = new FileOutputStream(outPath)) {

    xlsxFile.getSheetAt(0).createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("test");
    xlsxFile.write(pOuts);


} catch (IOException | InvalidFormatException | EncryptedDocumentException ex) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Indeed, if I use a FileInputStream instead, nothing is written to the template file. Seems to be a clean solution, whereas 'Try with resources' does not help.

Comment: As Axel Richter pointed out, both close() and write() methods need to have the file writeable, which will always lead to the template file being written to.

Answer (score 1):

The "solution" to making the template file read only can only work if we do ignoring the `FileNotFoundException...(permission denied)` caused by  `POIXMLDocument.close` then. And we should setting the file writable after processing for further using.

So the following will work:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

class ReadAndWriteExcelWorkbook {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  File templatefile = new File("file.xlsx");

  templatefile.setWritable(true);
  try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(templatefile)) { //at this point the file must be writable
  //try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(templatefile, null, true)) { //this will not work

   Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

   for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
    Row row = sheet.getRow(r);
    if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(r);
    Cell cell = row.getCell(r);
    if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(r);
    cell.setCellValue("changed");
   }

   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("fileNew.xlsx");
   workbook.write(out);
   out.close();

   templatefile.setWritable(false);

  } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException ioex) {
   ioex.printStackTrace(); //we simply do ignoring this FileNotFoundException
  }

  templatefile.setWritable(true);

 }
}
```

Notes:

While `WorkbookFactory.create(templatefile)` the `templatefile` must be writable because it defaults to [WorkbookFactory.create](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create-java.io.File-java.lang.String-boolean-) having `boolean readOnly` set to `false`. So if the `templatefile` is set read only at this time, the  `WorkbookFactory.create(templatefile)` would fail.

We cannot using `WorkbookFactory.create(templatefile, null, true)` - having `boolean readOnly` set to `true` - because this would fail at `workbook.write` while `POIXMLDocument.write` while committing the changes to the underlaying `OPCPackage`.

Comment: No, though I hoped this would be it, it is not. The template file is writeable when close() is called, and so it is file is changed. Obviously the only solution is to use a FileInputStream.

Comment: Using FileInputStream to avoid this glitch in the poi API should be the accepted solution (although it does not precisely match the question).